# Using .htaccess to mask a sub-domain redirect to shopify.com

Tags: .htaccess, dns, masking, shopify

I am currently using bluehost a registrar for my domain *www.exampledomain.com*.  I created a sub-domain redirect using bluehost C-panel to make a sub domain *shop.exampledomain.com* that redirects to *exampledomain.myshopify.com*

I want the url of the sub-domain to mask the url of the shopify domain.  So if you click on shop from the root, it would redirect to the sub-domain *shop.exampledomain.com* and re-write this for every url masking the *exampledomain.myshopify.com*

I have used godaddy before and they offer a feature that does this, but I can't transfer do to an e-mail setup.  Bluehost says they do not offer this feature, but they do offer .htaccess apache and php.  If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

firstly DO NOT redirect. just create the subdomain `shop.example.com` and in it's root directory put an htaccess file with following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exampledomain.shopify.com/$1 [NC, L]
```